# How to create a download link in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to put links on my Symfony2 project where people can download files by clicking a link. However, at the moment when a user clicks on a link I get the following error:

> No route found for "GET /uploads/test/test-audio-live.wmv"

How do I allow downloads without this error appearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file actually exists, it should not be even processed by Symfony or PHP. If you get this error it means that Symfony is looking up a route to serve this url, thus your file does not really exist in the public folder. Check your directiories.

Comment: Tony Bogdanov is correct, just be 100% certain your typing is correct for the path to file and the file name. A common error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to place the file in `test-audio-live.wmv` in your `web/uploads/test` folder and make it readable to the apache user.

Also make sure the virtual host of apache (if you're using apache) is configured so that the root directory is `web`. I guess this is also done by the .htaccess, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To create a downloadable link, please make sure you have any **uploads** directory or similar any directory in  **web/** directory of your application. Assume you have PDF files in **web/pdf/** directory with file **catalog.pdf** and you want to create a downloadable link for it in Symfony the you can do it by the following code

```
<a href="{{ asset('pdf/') }}catalog.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

The **asset** will directly point to the **web** folder of your application.

Once you click on the link it will open in the new tab as I have added target="_blank"