# How to create a link to download generated documents in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Documents are created by the system and saved to the folder /web/downloads. I have created a view to display links which will allow a user to download the files, should the user click the links. (standard click to download feature)

I am new to Symfony2 and am getting around the whole routing/controller concept, but how would one create a link to such files while still adhering to the MVC? Does one need to set up routing with a controller or does twig have features which allow it etc.

PS:
I have read questions such as [How to create a download link in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590789/how-to-create-a-download-link-in-symfony2) but i do not get if they did something in the routing or just added links etc.

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's make a sample.

Say your project lives in /www/, so /www/web/ is the document root of your symfony2 application. Now everything you try to access that is in /www/web/ over http://server/ will show up.

/www/web/downloads/file.zip would be reachable at http://server/downloads/file.zip by default.

Comment: ok, just to double check that i understand what you are saying.
I construct a normal link (within the view) which simply has href="/downloads/filename.extention" and symfony would handle the rest to make it turn out as http://server/downloads/filename.extention, which then works?

Comment: In all the cases I used it, yes.

Answer (score 41):

Sample implementation would be,

Create a route,

```
download_route:
    pattern:  /download/{filename}
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Controller:download }
```

And then in your controller,

```
public function downloadAction($filename)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(). "/../web/downloads/";
    $content = file_get_contents($path.$filename);

    $response = new Response();

    //set headers
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'mime/type');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$filename);

    $response->setContent($content);
    return $response;
}
```

For generating download link check [Generating urls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls) section of the doc.

Comment: Thank you for this controller based example. Will implement to see how it works.

Comment: I marked Christian's answer as accepted because it was the appropriate one for the problem scope i had. But your answer is also correct and we intend to use it in other areas of the project. Thank you once again.

Comment: I upvoted this answer too, because it's an alternative. The problem though should NEVER be solved this way, if it's simply a file to be publicly linkable. Only ever use this approach with files that are outside of the public webspace, where you can't link them in with something else (like an alias in apache) or when you need a logic applied (access restrictions, IP limits and such) that you need to control inside your application.

Comment: @ChristianRiesen, another use case of my approach would be to stop browser to process the files. For example you want to give user an option to download a image or pdf file. Browser will automatically show the image or open the pdf in browser if adobe plugin is installed. Adding `Content-Disposition` in header will ensure that browser will always prompt for download dialog.

Comment: @m2mdas Yes, very good catch, I use that a lot myself. Of course any other header would also be relevant in this case, like caching and so on. though with the right .htaccess or similar mechanism in other servers you could manipulate the headers for a specific directory just the same. As a side note: Use readfile instead of file_get_contents if you simply stream the file out (and use exit after). Saves a lot of headaches for larger files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 6):

Just adding the path of the file to the `href` attribute didn't work for me.

When clicked, it just displays the file without really downloading it.

What worked for me though is adding a `download` attribute to my link which is an HTML5 attribute.  Just add the attribute like so:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Download Link</a>
```

Upon clicking the link, it will just download the file without any server side code.

You can also assign a value to the `download` attribute.

```
<a href="path/to/file" download="filename.txt">Download Link</a>
```

The value of the `download` attribute will be used as the file name of the downloaded file instead of the one used while it was stored on the server.

I followed the [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) in the Symfony website regarding file upload handling.  I found it helpful when I was figuring out how to make a download link for the file.  I just added a method to the `Document` entity called `getDownloadFileName()` which just returns the file name I want to assign to the `download` attribute.

So basically, this is how I implemented it on my Symfony project's twig template

```
<a href="{{ asset(file.webPath) }}" download="{{ file.downloadFileName }}">
Download Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the best solution i came up with so far, it allows you to serve downloads from outside of your "/var/www/web/" folder, which makes the file not 
accessible without running this script used to serve the file.

This way you can check if the downloader has permission to download the file he wants.

In this example i used "/var/www/downloads/" where i store all files i want to serve as a download:

```
/**
 * http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html
 */
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

class OfflineToolController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function downloadAction()
    {
        $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(). "/../downloads/"; 
        $file = $path.'my_file.zip'; // Path to the file on the server
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);

        // Give the file a name:
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,'my_file_name.zip');

        return $response;
    }

}
```

source: 
docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html

(should work on versions above 2.2)

Comment: What version of Symfony is this supposed to work in? I guess not in mine (2.0). I know, I work with a very old one...

Comment: Not really sure what version this was for, i think 2.2 according to the date of my answer and i know we used a recent version back then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this fits you, but keep this another ultra simple alternative in mind:

i.e. in your view:

```
<a class='north' href="{{ asset('bundles/TP/Resume.pdf') }}" target="_blank" title="Download.pdf"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/TP/images/icn-save.jpg') }}" alt="Download the pdf version" /></a>
```

It opens the file, and the user has the decision if he wants to print it, download it... etc