# How to create a link that download a file in Symfony

Tags: file, symfony, pdf, hyperlink, download

I did some research and I found this post:
[How to create a link to download generated documents in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122807/how-to-create-a-link-to-download-generated-documents-in-symfony2)

I tried the solution, but it show my pdf in the browser, but what I want is that when someone click the link, it directly download the file. Is ther a way to do that with Symfony?

Kévin Duguay

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set up an action.
This uses annotation for the route. YOu can of course use yml or xml or whatever you are currently using

```
/**
 * @Route("/download", name="download_file")
**/
public function downloadFileAction(){
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse('path/to/pdf.pdf');
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,'pdf.pdf');
    return $response;
}
```

Twig template:

```
<a href="{{path('download_file')}}">Download file</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but just one question, how do I call that action with a link AND I don't want the link to change my page?

Comment: I suppose you use twig for your view so you have to find the route identifier of this method using php app/console router:debug then do :
<a href="{{ path('ROUTE_IDENTIFIER') }}">Download pdf</a>. Pretty sure it won't reload your page

Comment: @KévinDuguayI updated my answer. With the content disposition set to attachment it will not change your page or reload it.

Comment: The exact class namespace is: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse (don't forget use)