# Display/Download a file from server using Symfony2 and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

Using Symfony2.0 and jQuery

My application generates and stores PDF outside the ./www folder as it is private information (comercial invoices for the purchases within my shop).

I am trying and not getting to allow the customer to download their invoices at any time.

I found this article, but at the beginning it talks about how to get them from the "public" ./www folder. At the end, it offers a piece of code, but I think it is not supported by my version of Symfony:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

class OfflineToolController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @return BinaryFileResponse
 */
public function downloadAction()
{
    $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(). "/../downloads/"; 
    $file = $path.'my_file.zip'; // Path to the file on the server
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);

    // Give the file a name:
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,'my_file_name.zip');

    return $response;
    }

}
```

This is the case: [How to create a link to download generated documents in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122807/how-to-create-a-link-to-download-generated-documents-in-symfony2)

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Exemple from @m2mdas in this post is pretty simple and clear. What is not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122807/how-to-create-a-link-to-download-generated-documents-in-symfony2