# Symfony 4 - Download file from project directory

Tags: symfony, download, twig

In my `public` folder, I placed a .txt file to be downloaded once the user clicks on the download button.

In my controller, I put `path` as a variable to be passed in the template.

```
$context['path'] = '/public/sample.txt';
```

In my twig file, I have:

```
<a href="{{ path }}">Download</a>
```

However, when I click the link, the download fails and a file is not found. Is there a simple way to make this work?

Here is what appears when I click the link:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlOiJ.png)

Comment: Hi JM. This question is "too generic" for have an answer. Plase, try to add more details, like (for instance) what does it means that "download fails" and this kind of useful infos. BTW take a look to [this link](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper)

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20658401/8411841 You need to write a controller action as your file can not be downloaded directly.

Answer (score 8):

The right way to download a static file according [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files) is:

`$response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($file);`

And/or add headers and Content-Diposition:

`$response->headers->set('Content-Type','text/plain');
 $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'sample.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can work:

```
$context['path'] = '/sample.txt';
```

Have you tried this?